# Por qué falla este servicio de gitea en ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: ubuntu, git

Estoy intentado instalar gitea en ubuntu 20.10, todo bien pero me arroja un error al iniciar el servicio

**Esto es lo que tengo en gitea.sirvice**

```
[Unit]
Description=Gitea (Git con una taza de té)
After=syslog.target
After=network.target
Requires=mysql.service

[Service]
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
LimitNOFILE=65535
RestartSec=2s
Type=simple
User=git
Group=git
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/gitea/
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gitea web --config /etc/gitea/app.ini
Restart=always
Environment=USER=git HOME=/home/git GITEA_WORK_DIR=/var/lib/gitea
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**sudo systemctl status gitea**

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gitea.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-02-16 17:22:26 UTC; 1s ago
    Process: 363787 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gitea web --config /etc/gitea/app.ini (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 363787 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

**journalctl -xe**

```
>Feb 16 17:51:32 mosere.com gitea[375476]: 2021/02/16 17:51:32 cmd/web.go:107:runWeb() [I] Starting Gitea on PID: 375476
Feb 16 17:51:32 mosere.com gitea[375476]: 2021/02/16 17:51:32 ...dules/setting/git.go:91:newGit() [I] Git Version: 2.27.0, Wire Protocol Version 2 Enabled
Feb 16 17:51:32 mosere.com gitea[375476]: 2021/02/16 17:51:32 routers/init.go:84:GlobalInit() [F] Git module init failed: Failed to set git user.name(exec(3:git.Init(s>
Feb 16 17:51:32 mosere.com gitea[375476]:         ): error: could not lock config file /home/git/.gitconfig: Permission denied
Feb 16 17:51:32 mosere.com gitea[375476]:
Feb 16 17:51:32 mosere.com systemd[1]: gitea.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Comment: Y qué ves en `journalctl -xe` cuando le das `systemctl start gitea`? Por favor, responde **editando** tu pregunta y añadiendo esta información.

Comment: Listo puede ser este el error? error: could not lock config file /home/git/.gitconfig: Permission denied

Comment: Muy posiblemente. Ese paquete parece que necesitase permisos sobre tu `.gitconfig` porque parece que va a configurar tu nombre y tu email allí (para identificar tus commits). Y ese archivo está en el home de tu usuario.

Comment: Gracias son los permisos. funciona con chmod 777 /home/git/

Comment: Revisa la documentación, para ver si eso es lo que indican que se requiere. Si es así, puedes poner tu solución como respuesta :)

Comment: 777 suena como un overkill. Apostado que los archivos dentro de un repo git no son ejecutables.